# AJAX POST da error 500 en HTTPS, pero no en HTTP

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl

Hace un mes cambié el servidor de HTTP a HTTPS (SSL), aunque no sé si tendrá que ver. El caso es que una pequeña aplicación que tenía programada en web muy rudimentaria, pero funcionaba bien en Noviembre. Hoy la he vuelto a abrir, y no funciona.

Entre otras cosas, la primera pantalla es una petición de usuario y contraseña. Al enviar esos datos, hago una comprobación por AJAX contra una base de datos mysql, para comprobar que el usuario exista, y así poder continuar. Pues eso ya no funciona.

**Código JQUERY:**

    `$("#confirmarUSUARIO").click(function() {
        usuario = $("#txtUSUARIO").val();
        password = $("#txtPASSWORD").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "inc/confirmarUSUARIO.php",
            data: {usuario:usuario,password:password},
            success: function(confirmacion){
                if(confirmacion) {
                    window.location.href = "consultas.html";
                } else {
                    location.reload();
                }
            },
        }); 
    });`

**Código confirmarUSUARIO.php**

    `require 'conexion.php';
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $datos = confirmarUSUARIO($pdo,$usuario,$password);
    echo $datos;`

**Código confirmarUSUARIO dentro de conexion.php**

`function confirmarUSUARIO($pdo,$usuario,$password) {
    $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND password=?");
    $sentencia->bindParam(1, $usuario);
    $sentencia->bindParam(2, $password);
    $sentencia->execute();
    if($sentencia->rowCount()==0) {
        $datos = false;
    } else {
        $datos = true;
    }
    return $datos;
}`

Como veis, es rudimentario, pero para un par de chorradas que tengo que hacer con ello, va rápido y funciona bien.

Ahora, después de cambiar a SSL, me da un error 500.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de porqué pasa?

NOTA: Tengo un duplicado de todo en el equipo local corriendo con XAMPP y funciona sin problemas.

$pdo lo inicializo en conexion.php 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $usuario, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Por otro lado, la base de datos es la misma en servidor que en local, con la diferencia de los datos de conexion

---

$pdo lo inicializo en conexion.php

`$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $usuario, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Por otro lado, la base de datos es la misma en servidor que en local, con la diferencia de los datos de conexion

Comment: si estas inicializando la variable $pdo, no veo que estés realizando la coneión?

Comment: El error HTTP500, implica un error en el código del servicio web al que has llamado. Es decir, tienes que tener un log en la parte del servidor, donde se indique el problema. Por otro lado, dices que en local te funciona, pero en el servidor no. Eso tiene pinta de ser un problema de conexión a base de datos, o alguna discrepancia entre el modelo de datos de tu copia local y del servidor, por ejemplo. Por otra parte: ¿Está arrancada la base de datos en el servidor?  Te diría que lo primero que tienes que hacer, es localizar los logs del servicio al que llamas, para saber qué le pasa.